# 400 Bad Request | Your request has bad syntax or is inherently impossible to satisfy

Tags: php, mysql

I am an intermediate web developer trying to give a shot on creating websites. I coded my website in HTML and PHP. Installed XAMPP as the back-end server. Then tried accessing the localhost from my pc, then it worked very well. Now, I setup my JioFi router ( Those who are new to jiofi refer google ) for forwarding port 80.

[image]

After setting it up when I chose my public IP which is xx.xx.xxx.xxx it shows

> 400 Bad Request | Your request has bad syntax or is inherently impossible to satisfy.

[image]

This is my code

Post data input

````
<head>
<title>
Post Data Test
</title>
</head>
<form method = "POST" action = "Post Data Process.php">
Type your name below:  <!-- This helps the user understand where the data should be inputted -->
<br>
<br>
<input type=text name = 'name'> </br>   <!-- Name is collected -->
</input>
<br>
<button style = "background-color: black; color: white;" type = submit name = 'submit'>Submit</button>
<br>
<br>
</html>
&copy; 2010-<?php echo date("Y");?>     All rights reserved <br>
The website is managed by Advait Inc. ```
````

Post data process and output

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo $name;
echo '<br><br>';
?>
&copy; 2010-<?php echo date("Y");?>
```

Comment: You could use a `<html>` tag and a `<body>` tag in there my friend

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/HTML_basics

Comment: WOudl be useful to see your virtual host definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem the issue was with cookies in my pc. It worked on my samsung device. Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a proper HTML document structure.

For example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My test page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Some content</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens in chrome mainly because chrome tries to redirect `http`://mytestsite.com to `https`://mytestsite.com all because of Chrome strict HSTS policy. HTTP Strict Transport Security is a way for sites to always use HTTPS.

If you try to open the same website on other browser like Microsoft Edge, Firefox or on your mobile device it might not happen there.

Fix:

Go to `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`

[image]

Now test again your `http`://mytestsite.com on chrome. Hopefully it will work now.

I faced the same issue and hot help from [here](https://howchoo.com/chrome/stop-chrome-from-automatically-redirecting-https#:%7E:text=Why%20this%20happens,a%20valid%20SSL%2FTLS%20certificate.)